# Cannot create database connection for Doctrine2 in Symfony2 with MAMP (Connection refused)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm in the process of learning Symfony2 for a project that me and some friends are taking on, and am taking a tutorial where you make a blog in Symfony2: http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/doctrine-2-the-blog-model.html

**Problem**

I can't seem to get Doctrine2 to work. I give the following instruction to the Terminal:

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

And get the following error message:

> Could not create database for connection named `symfony`
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

**System info**

I have a mac that runs Mountain lion and I use MAMP.

**What I have done**

I went to the config page (`http://localhost/NameOfProject/web/config.php`) and went to the place where you configure your database. There I put in the path, port, user, password, etc from the MAMP start page.

**What I have tried**

A blog I came across suggested to create a symbolic link to the the MAMP mysql socket with the following command:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock mysql.sock
```

This did not make the error go away for me.

**Some of my files in symfony (if they are relevant)**

From `app/config/config.yml`:

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: '8889'
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: root
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: 0408312e2b9861c0c86dbb7488aceec4296054ec
    database_path: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

From `app/config/parameters.yml`:

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: '8889'
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: root
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: 0408312e2b9861c0c86dbb7488aceec4296054ec
    database_path: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

The tutorial talks updating the database_* options in the parameters file located at `app/config/parameters.ini`. However, I don't have a `parameters.ini` file located in this folder! Only `parameters.yml`.

**Edit: Solution:**

I was using the wrong port number for MySql. When I used 3306 it worked.

Comment: Are you sure you need to specify database_path? Also 'Connection refused' suggests that host was found and nobody is listening on that particular port. Does your `mysql` listen on port 8889? Standard `mysql` port is 3306...

Comment: Unless I misunderstood something, jperovic, it seems your answer was given as a comment, and thus I cannot officially "accept" your answer. But thanks a lot anyway!! :)

Comment: Ah, yeah, that was just a suggestion. I will write an answer now in order for you to successfully close the question ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was using the wrong port number for MySql. When I used 3306, the standard mysql port, it worked. 
(Thank you jperovic)

Comment: For those who still can't resolve this problem, try to enable `Allow network access to MySQL` in MAMP settings.